# Create a toggle Button Similar to the Image attached

Tags: wpf, xaml

[image]

```
I want to have two buttons which behave similar to Radio Button Functionality plus can also handle the button click or Command functionality if using MVVM.
```

I tried to create the control template inside the ToggleButton template. The UI looks similar to this but I have used text block as a control within stack panel. Now if I replace the textblock with the Button the Behaviour changes.

```
 Below is my XAML :

     <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2">
                                            <ToggleButton.Template>
                                                <ControlTemplate>
                                                    <Border Name="ControlBorder" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="CodeTextBlockStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                                <TextBlock Name="CodeTextBlock" Text="Code" Width="50" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                                </TextBlock>
                                                            </StackPanel>
                                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="ScanTextBlockStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                                <TextBlock Name="ScanTextBlock" Text="Scan" Width="50" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
                                                            </StackPanel>
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </Border>
                                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                            <Setter TargetName="CodeTextBlockStackPanel" Property="Opacity" Value="0.25"/>
                                                            <Setter TargetName="ScanTextBlockStackPanel" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="False">
                                                            <Setter TargetName="ScanTextBlockStackPanel" Property="Opacity" Value="0.25"/>
                                                            <Setter TargetName="CodeTextBlockStackPanel" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </ToggleButton.Template>
                                        </ToggleButton>
```

Any change or suggestion on how this could be accomplished would be helpful

Comment: In what way the behaviour changes? And why would you use buttons inside a ToggleButton? Pls share more information. Obviously a `Button` will handle your `Click-Event` and it wont go through it. So there is a different behaviour.

Comment: Using Button does not fire the triggers that I have used on the stack panel in which the button is placed. It works fine if I am using text block.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after, but are you trying to put a <Button/> inside this <ToggleButton/> Template? Because if you are, it won't work - the two will conflict.

Comment: I wanted it to function like a switch. And also when user click on that button for example Code button within the Toggle button template it should fire the code for that and similar for the Scan button.

Answer (score 0):

The other behaviour is caused by a `Button` taking your `Click`-`Event`.
If you dont need `Button`s inside of it and just want the click Event, then use a `Behaviour` like this.

```
public class ClickBehaviour : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
    {



        public ICommand MouseClickCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(MouseClickCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MouseClickCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MouseClickCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseClickCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MouseClickCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ClickBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(null));






        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown += AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown;

            base.OnAttached();
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown -= AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            base.OnDetaching();
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MouseClickCommand?.Execute(null);

        }
    }
```

If you get still issues set e.Handeld in the `AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown` on `FALSE`

Dont forget to reference the Interactivity-Assembly.

Use Behaviours like this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:interactivity="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2">
            <ToggleButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Name="ControlBorder" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="CodeTextBlockStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock Name="CodeTextBlock" Text="Code" Width="50" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                                </TextBlock>
                                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <local:ClickBehaviour MouseClickCommand="{Binding Path=MyC}" />
                                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="ScanTextBlockStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock Name="ScanTextBlock" Text="Scan" Width="50" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
                                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <local:ClickBehaviour MouseClickCommand="{Binding Path=MyC}"  />
                                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="CodeTextBlockStackPanel" Property="Opacity" Value="0.25"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ScanTextBlockStackPanel" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="ScanTextBlockStackPanel" Property="Opacity" Value="0.25"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="CodeTextBlockStackPanel" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.Template>
        </ToggleButton>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```